# Why am I getting "System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject does not contain a definition"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm creating and accessing a dynamic property in a .Net 4.0 WPF application and it's throwing an exception when trying to access the setter property, can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
 dynamic signOffItem = new ExpandoObject();

 signOffItem.Currency = "GBP";
 signOffItem.Commentary = "Blah...";
 signOffItem.IsIncluded = true;

 var tmp = signOffItem.IsIncluded;
 Debug.WriteLine(tmp);
```

This works in a test but not in a WPF app.

Comment: Your code work fine, the only problems i find was `Debug.WriteLine(tmp);` but is for the conditional (.NET 4.5, VS2012).

Comment: Yeah just written a simple test for it and it works, but in WPF app it's not working...

Comment: Are you sure `IsIncluded` is spelt the same both times?

Comment: yeah it spelt the same :)

Comment: Ok i created a WPF app, added a button in main window and a click event running your code and no problems (VS2012, .NET 4.0).

Comment: Well its working for everyone other than @AwkwardCoder. Something's awkward here :) . Are you able to execute this code snippet in a simple test program??  Also is it the very first property i.e. signOffItem.Currency where you get this exception??

Comment: Need to use properties not fields if you are trying to use xaml bindings.

Comment: This object is bound up in XAML and that works perfectly fine, the problem only occurs when trying to access the property as above in a view model. There must be something wrong with the WPF project.

Comment: Post the full code behind and xaml.

Comment: that is pretty much it...